# postgresql - how to calculate the percentage of number of entries in one table w.r.t to no of entries in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables(A & B) in my database(c). both tables contains two coulmns as shown below

```
 column name   Datatype

eventtime     timestamp without time zone
serialnumber  numeric
```

Table A contains total number of products (good and downgraded -- but in these table they are not defined as affected/downgraded) produced in each day. And table B contains total number of only downgraded products.

I want to make an quality process control chart using the percentage of downgraded products w.r.t total number of products produced (using serialnumber to join for example).

could some one tell me how can i get the percentage value for each day (also for each hour)

Comment: Do you need the percentage for every serialnumber or for all products?

Comment: for all products. (eachserial number represents one product/finished good)

Comment: for example in table A i have 700 finished goods/products on 29.11.2015 and 800 on 30.11.2015. in table B i have 30 on 29.11.2015 and 45 on 30.11.2015. something like this  29.11.2015   4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to group rows by desired period, e.g.:

```
select 
    a.r_date::date date, 
    downgraded,
    total, 
    round(downgraded::numeric/total* 100, 2) percentage
from (
    select date_trunc('day', eventtime) r_date, count(*) downgraded
    from b
    group by 1
    ) b
join (
    select date_trunc('day', eventtime) r_date, count(*) total
    from a
    group by 1
    ) a
using (r_date)
order by 1;

    date    | downgraded | total | percentage 
------------+------------+-------+------------
 2015-05-05 |          3 |     4 |      75.00
 2015-05-06 |          1 |     4 |      25.00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Bingooo Klin. Thank you very much. it served my purpose completely.